# Removing eprint and eprinttype in citation notes

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, footnotes

**QUESTION EDITED:** I am using the command `\autocite` for referencing using the note and bibliography style. The footnotes include eprint and eprinttype, how can I prevent that from occuring? Here is an examples of a footnote with parts in bold when I don't want that information:

1. C. A. Bayly, “The Pre-History of ’Communalism’ ? Religious Conflict in India, 1700-1860,” Modern Asian Studies 19, no. 2 (January 1, 1985): 177–203, **JSTOR: 312153**.

my `.tex` file:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }

\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[notes,strict,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,backend=biber,autolang=other,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{dissertation-ref.bib}

\begin{document}

This is an attempt at a minimal example.\autocite{Bayly1985PreHistory}

\end{document}
```

---My `dissertation-ref.bib` file:

```
@article{Bayly1985PreHistory,
  title = {The Pre-History of 'Communalism'? Religious Conflict in India, 1700-1860},
  volume = {19},
  rights = {Copyright © 1985 Cambridge University Press},
  issn = {0026-749X},
  shorttitle = {The Pre-History of 'Communalism'?},
  timestamp = {2015-03-18 11:14:32},
  eprinttype = {jstor},
  eprint = {312153},
  number = {2},
  journal = {Modern Asian Studies},
  author = {Bayly, C. A.},
  date = {1985-01-01},
  pages = {177--203},
  keywords = {communalism},
}
```

Comment: I think what we need to see here is a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) in order to have the slightesst clue of what might be going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `eprint` by using a `\clearfield{eprint}` command when you call a cite key. Namely, you need `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{eprint}}`

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[notes,strict,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,backend=biber,autolang=other,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{dissertation-ref.bib}

\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{eprint}}

\begin{document}

This is an attempt at a minimal example.\autocite{Bayly1985PreHistory}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This fixes the issue with the footnotes. I integrated this code into my larger file and now I notice that the problem still remains in the bilbiography section

Comment: To remove the eprint completely use the `eprint=false` option of `biblatex`

Comment: This solves this issue. Another issue I notice is that journal articles sometimes include 'accessed by <date>'. In the .bib file, journal entries sometimes include `url` and `urldate` fields, these exist because i use the zotero plugin to pull journal article fields from the internet. Setting  `url=false` in biblatex should have turned this off but no luck. Any work around to remove the  fields from citations?

Comment: `url=false` should do. You can try to use `\clearfield{url}`